# WS02 G-REG new metadata type

Tags: wso2

We're testing G-Reg for use of a SOA repository. The default types are Services, WSDL's, Schemas and WS Policies, we're triying to add a new type (Persons for example).
Once added, we want to create a xml to specify the fields that needs to be filled to upload a new resource of the "Persons" type, (like the Services type actual funcionality).

We've followed the guide on http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance411/Configurable+Governance+Artifacts, but with no success of creating the example named "Events", because there exists contradictory information, the path "/_system/governance/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.governance/types", doesn't exists on GREG 4.1.1, so where is supposed the content to be uploaded?

And, the guide explains about a "registry extension file" and a "content", which is the difference between them?, they need a name?, content.xml and extfile.xml perhaps?

Any orientation will be greatly appreciated

Thanks,
Gabriel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample server.rxt file I have created.

<artifactType type="application/vnd.wso2-server+xml" shortName="server" singularLabel="Server" pluralLabel="Servers" hasNamespace="false" iconSet="5">
    <storagePath>/servers/@{overview_name}/</storagePath>
    <ui>
        <list>
            <column name="Name">
                <data type="path" value="overview_name" href="@{storagePath}"/>
            </column>
        </list>
    </ui>
    <content>
    <table name="Overview">
        <field type="text" required="true">
            <name label="name">Name</name>
        </field>
        <field type="text" required="true">
            <name label="url">url</name>
        </field>
        <field type="text" required="true">
            <name label="username">username</name>
        </field>
        <field type="text" required="true">
            <name label="password">password</name>
        </field>
    </table>
    </content>
</artifactType>

you need to save this under the directory you have mentioned.

/_system/governance/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.governance/types

this location is not exits. But you need to create this directory and save.

After restart you should see the new type under meta data list